# Tate's theorem about abelian variteies in case of abelian scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

For $k$ a finite field , $A,A'$ an abelian varieties over  $k$, $G$ the Galois group of $k$, $l$ a prime number different from the characteristic of $k$ . Tate has proved that:

$Q_l\otimes Hom_k(A,A')\rightarrow Hom_G(V_l(A),V_l(A'))$
is bijective ,  where $V_l(A)=Q_l\otimes_{Z_l}T_l(A)$  , $T_l(A)$ is the Tate module of $A$.

Now consider a Scheme  $S$ over $F_p$, and Abelian  schemes $A,A'$ over $S$ , is there any known result similar to  Tate's theorem for this situation?

Thank you !

Comment: Zarhin proved this when $S$ is a curve.

Comment: Can you give me the reference ?Thank you!

Comment: Zarhin, Ju. G. Isogenies of abelian varieties over fields of finite characteristic. (Russian) Mat. Sb. (N.S.) 95(137) (1974), 461–470, 472.